# Could Git Bash run daemon process periodically?

Tags: bash, daemon, windows-server

I have this `myscript.sh` act as a performance monitor in Windows Server. To do so, I'm using Git Bash to run the script but the problem is the script just execute it once after  I put the command to run it. Is there any command that I can use to run it in daemon or maybe  let the script run periodically based on our time interval?

Comment: Running a program periodically ist not something which is defined in the realm of bash, which is just a programming language and does not have any intrinsic knowledge of the services in the operating system it is running. On Unix/Linux for instance, you could use `cron` to run something as a service.  Since this is not a question about programming, but about operating system configuration, I suggest that you ask this at [su].

Comment: Seems like I still need to have Unix/Linux to make things work. Btw, thanks for the answer and recommendation.

Comment: I don't think so. I know that Windows **does** have the capability of running periodic tasks; I'm just not a Windows guy and can't tell you how to do it. However, at [su] Windows is discussed as well, and I consider it likely that you will get an answer there. Another idea (if this suits you) is to switch from git-bash to Cygwin bash, where you can use `cron`. It just uses the Windows services under the hood, and you need to have local admin rights to make it fully functional.